# swift opaque type keyword some doesn't seem to make a difference

Tags: swift

In Apple's swift 5.1 language guide [example](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html) the keyword "some" doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
func makeTrapezoid() -> some Shape {
let top = Triangle(size: 2)
let middle = Square(size: 2)
let bottom = FlippedShape(shape: top)
let trapezoid = JoinedShape(
    top: top,
    bottom: JoinedShape(top: middle, bottom: bottom)
)
return trapezoid
}
let trapezoid = makeTrapezoid()
//print(trapezoid.draw())


let sh:Shape = trapezoid
print("type:\(type(of:sh))")
```

This prints `type:JoinedShape<Triangle, JoinedShape<Square, FlippedShape<Triangle>>>` with or without the "some" keyword.

I thought the point of "some" was to hide the type???

Comment: What difference did you expect it to make?

Comment: If "some" makes no difference then what is the point of it?  The return type isn't being hidden.

Comment: Yes it is, it's hidden from the static type system. I think you're kind of missing the point of `some`. Types of objects are always visible in Swift. They're observable from the debugger, from `type(of:)`, the `is`/`as` operators. `some` doesn't exist to hide types and make them completely undiscoverable through all these channels. Instead, its purpose is to make it so the static type system can prevent you from relying on any APIs of the result besides those offered by the interface.

Comment: In this case, you can't do anything on the result besides what is part of the `Share` protocol. Even though the concrete type here is `JoinedShape`, you can't call any APIs on the result that aren't defined in the `Shape` protocol. This way, you're free to change the concrete type of the return value in the future, and you can be confident that so long as your new return value conforms to the protocol, no caller code will break, because no caller code relied on anything beyond what the protocol offers.

Comment: What is the difference then between func someFunc() -> some SomeProtocol and func someFunc() -> SomeProtocol ?  Using the type returned I'm able to call a method not defined in SomeProtocol in either case using as!.

Comment: I’d suggest watching WWDC video [What’s New in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/402/?time=1535), or refer to [The Swift Programming Language: Opaque Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html) or [Swift Evolution SE-0244](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md).

Comment: Rob I referred to the language guide in my OP.   If it was clear I wouldn't be posting here.  Further I tried what Alexander suggested in a playground and it doesn't hold true, at least as per what I understood he said.

Comment: Of course you can get around it with `as!`. That's not the point. The point is that your public API guarantees that the object you return conforms to `SomeProtocol`, and makes no other guarantees. If people want to force cast the result to a concrete type, they're welcome to do that, but they should know that they're relying on an implementation detail (the concrete type) which you haven't guaranteed wouldn't change (if you did want to make guarantees about the concrete type, then you would just make the return type be concrete type). Watch the video Rob linked.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I thought the point of `some` was to hide the type???

The point is that the caller doesn’t need to be exposed to how we created the trapezoid (i.e., that `makeTrapezoid` returns a `JoinedShape<Triangle, JoinedShape<Square, FlippedShape<Triangle>>>` is irrelevant). The caller really shouldn’t care how it was implemented. All it needs to be aware of is that the returned object conforms to `Shape`.

Just like when you return a standard protocol-as-type value, this doesn’t change the object that is actually returned at run-time. In this case, it is still that messy `JoinedShape` type. All it means is that at compile-time, we’ve told the caller to not worry about the implementation details and to only rely upon the fact that it will conform to `Shape`.

You ask:

> What is the difference then between
>
> ```
> func someFunc() -> some SomeProtocol
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> func someFunc() -> SomeProtocol
> ```

The main difference is that if the protocol has `Self` or associated type requirements, you’re simply not permitted to do the latter. Opaque return types now allows us to easily do what used to require cumbersome work-arounds.

According to “Limitations of Returning a Protocol Type” in [What’s New in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/402/?time=1535), this new opaque return type allows the compiler to do additional optimizations and preserves type identity, too.

---

FWIW, if you’re interested in greater detail about the rationale behind the opaque return types, it’s outlined in greater detail in [Swift Evolution SE-0244](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md). And, for the sake of future readers, the high level summary is available in [The Swift Language: Opaque Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html).